# What's the fastest algorithm to evaluate 10,000 rules?

Tags: algorithm

I have pricing rules to determine how much discount I would give to customer. Problem is I need lots of rules, like ~10,000 rules, and the performance would be very slow if I were to loop all 10,000 rules for each customer request.

There are many conditions that I need to check to apply certain discount:

```
- Product type (clothes, electronics, etc)
- Product SKU
- Customer location
- Search date (e.g. >= 2019-01-01 And <= 2019-01-31)
- .
- .
- .
- ~30th conditions
```

Here are the example of rules I'd like to set:

```
Rule 1: product type = 'clothes', then discount 10%
Rule 2: product type = 'electronics', then discount 5%
Rule 3: product type = 'clothes' AND customer location = 'AUSTRALIA', then discount 7%
.
.
.
Rule 10,000: ....
```

Also I want to make each rule have priority. So if Rule 3 has higher priority than Rule 1, I want to apply discount using Rule 3.

The naive approach would be to loop all 10,000 rules and check each of the rules one by one whether they match the conditions or not. But the performance would be very bad. And what if I want to add another 10,000 rules.

I'm very interested to know if there is better approach for this instead of looping all rules.

--- update
This rule will need to be triggered everytime a user do search. There's a search bar which user can type the keywords he wants to find, and the page will return all the products that match the keywords. The result could reach up to 50 products, hence 50x we need to evaluate which rules applies to each product for each user search.

Comment: O(N) runtime should be sufficient as 10,000 isn't a lot. However, since you want certain rules to have priority, you should sort the rules by priority before looping. That way you can easily loop through all the rules once without having to check if its priority is higher than another rule.

Comment: I would argue that e.g. rule 3 (in your example) should have higher priority than rule 1. Otherwise you would *always* pick rule 1 and never even get to rule 3.

Comment: Same as @Someprogrammerdude said, you probably don't need to check all 10 000 rules.

Comment: This also seems like a possible case of *premature optimization*. Have you implemented and then *measured* that this rule-lookup is a bottleneck? How *often* do you need to do this rule-lookup? If you need to do it like a couple of time each minute, then unless you're on a very low-end system (like corresponding to computers two to three *decades* ago) it's not going to be a problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd assume this needs to execute every time someone is checking out.

Comment: If this actually becomes a problem you could filter out a lot of rules by indexing each product with the rules it conforms to. Then you can build a set of possible rules from a shopping cart. That would bring down the complexity from the number of rules to the number of items in the cart * number of promotions on an item.

Comment: @amin29 yes that's certain to sort all the rules first. But the problem is the time to evaluate all the rules.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude it needs to be executed everytime a user search. Probably ~50 request per second

Comment: @Michal indexing each product with the rule it conforms to would certainly make it faster. But what if after we indexed each product, there are still a lot of rules that will need to be executed, say 500 rules. Is there any different algorithm like compiling the rules to tree or anything else that could optimize the complexity to execute those rules?

Comment: Okay, then a simple loop might be a little excessive. Then my suggestion is some kind of tree structure. All rules which have a "product type" is in a common sub-branch (for example), with more specialized rules further down the tree. When selecting a rule go as far down the tree you can, as long as you have a match. The lowest matching node is the one you select. Most cases you shouldn't have to go down more than one or two levels of the tree, checking only a fraction of the rules.

Comment: Though, with a good multi-threaded application on a modern multi-core system, even a pretty naive and brute-force variant might be possible even for those requirements. Start with that, then *measure* and *profile* to find bottlenecks to fix (one by one). When (or rather *if*) there's nothing more to fix except this, and the performance is still not good enough, *then* you could look into different data structures, and start over with a good clean (and possibly naive) implementation and start over with the measuring and possible optimizations.

Comment: Yes, you could compile all the rules to form a decision tree. If all your rules are based on a handful of properties and simple Boolean conditions, creating that decision tree would not be terribly difficult. I'd need a more detailed list of requirements before I could develop an answer, though.

Comment: Indexing each product with the rules that apply to it is not a good idea at all. If you modified an existing rule or added a new one, you'd have to scan every product to update the list of rules that apply. With a tree of rules (which you can build from the rules database on load), you could add a new rule and update the tree in place. Deleting a rule is a bit more tricky. Probably you'd just want to leave it in the tree and mark it as deleted. Then rebuild the tree next time you restart the app.

Comment: Could you guys elaborate more on how to compile the rules and generate the tree? Is there any reference I could look up to?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of an overkill, but when I think speed, I think [Hash Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), where unique rules are stored as `(rule, discount)` pairs.

For this to work, you'll need to categorize your rule criteria (product type, country, etc). Second, you'll need to assign a number (enumerate) each member of each category:

`Countries[Australia = 1, New Zealand = 2, ...]`

After that, split all of the rules with multiple acceptable criteria into separate rules:

```
Rule 3: product type = 'clothes' AND (customer location = 'AUSTRALIA' OR customer location = 'NEW ZEALAND'), then discount 7%
```

becomes

```
Rule 4: product type = 'clothes' AND customer location = 'AUSTRALIA', then discount 7%
Rule 5: product type = 'clothes' AND customer location = 'NEW ZEALAND', then discount 7%
```

Now you have an array of criteria to check. If none are specified, you can leave a zero. For instance for array of criteria:

```
[product type, customer location, month]
```

you can have values

```
['decorations', '', 'December']
```

which translate to

```
[23, 0, 12]
```

and if you have a total of, say, 8 types of criteria you want to check, you have a final array that looks like this

```
[0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 12, 0]
```

Now is the time to check which is the specific rule that applies to this, by performing the [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Choosing_a_hash_function) `H()` on the array in some form. You could just string the digits together:

```
=H(0002300120)
```

or you could multiply each successive number with a greater power of 10 and then add them together (for less than ~25 criteria, because of 2<sup>64</sup> limit):

```
=H(230000 + 120000000)
```

The beauty of Hash Tables is that they work almost instantly with `O(1)`, if they are made with enough space to begin with and have both good hash functions `H()` and [collision resolving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) mechanism (because not all `H()` may be unique each time).

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I also want to have condition like: search date >= 2019-01-01 AND search date <= 2019-01-31. Also if you have rule ['decorations', '', 'december] and customer search with this fact ['decorations', 'India', 'december'], the rule wouldn't be applied since it's empty string for customer_location in the rule, but customer is from 'India'